# Where ist the best place in the rails app stack to put an early "ok ok" answer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

PRE

edit: -------------

remove the misleading: This a question about Hacker defense.

It is not a Question about defending potential Intruders, or security

I ask just for passing by known "friends", not to fill logs or alarms.

I try to clarify: I know that request blocking or redirecting is better handled with apache or alike.

The Scenario is, that I a have a small but mine Server for almost only private usage.

This - my - server I watch, as good as I can. I get alarms if something is happening, that should not.

I have the Module almost ready, the question is what to put here:

```
config.middleware.insert_before ?????, Friendly::SayYesOK
```

Additional I have a small but useful trick, that helps me identify kid hackers try to identify.

---

The Idea:

I want to answer already known bad HTTP(s) requests as early as possible with a "Yes, ok", like many know, ever sitting in a bar when an unwanted drunken tries to communicate.

I want to answer all "php", "joomla", "Wordpress", … attacks with an "ok" without filling my logs, without having this in any "page not found analyse"

But where to put such a module in Rails app stack - I think it should be before routes.rb is involved and after the request header is available.

I know how to, I don not not what level.

Ideas?

Comment: What, to you, is the difference between "hacker defense" and "security"?

Comment: @Schwern:  wanted to clarify, that this is not meant to rise security, to prevent answers going in that direction.

Comment: If for whatever reason you really really had to do this in Ruby [Rack Attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) is the way to go - you place it right at the top of the middleware stack so that it will reject requests before they hit the router. But @Schwern's suggestion on doing on the HTTP server layer is generally superior.

Comment: @max: Make this an Answer I vote it.
(I know that I could use my Apache, but  as a one man show, I prefer not to touch a running system, its not in my std. deployment path)

Comment: @halfbit "Hacker defense" would seem to be a security issue, so it remains unclear what you mean. Perhaps reword what you want without using those terms.

Comment: @Schwern - you are right - I try to over work that - I try to make clear, that it is ment to move well known bad request out of  sight.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put it in the Rails stack. Put a dedicated, lightweight HTTP server in front of your Rails app. [`nginx`](https://nginx.org/en/) is a good choice. Configure it to reject certain patterns of URLs and forward all other requests to your Rails app.

This server can also be a [load balancer](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html), [cache](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache), request logging, rate limiting, [a/b testing](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html), and can serve shared static files more efficiently than a Rails app. It is a very important part of a stable web stack.

For example, when you have a new release you can spin up your new release on new instances, test that they work (they effectively become your staging servers), change your world-facing server to redirect requests to the new instances, and then shut down the old instances. This allows upgrades with little or no downtime.

Comment: I know that, I know that this would be better, but as a "one man show" I try to keep things in my std deployment path.
It is nice to have - not a must.

Comment: @halfbit Applications made of multiple servers are very common and well in reach of a single developer. An app server (Rails), a queue, a database, a proxy, etc. Might be time to upgrade how you deploy.

Comment: Down voted - the question was "how to hold a nail", the answer don't use nails use screws is technicaly correct, but semanticaly wrong.

Comment: @halfbit If it's not about security, and it's not about performance, I'm not sure what you want. Perhaps edit your question to be clear what you want that standard Rails routing does not already provide. What "alarms" are going off? Do you just want to pretend that certain common 404 requests never happen?

Comment: its a matter of Honeypot. Not much more. :)